# post method not working

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, google-app-engine

I want to submit form data using post using ajax because in form post after submit it is redirected to a new page.

```
<form id="myContactForm">
    <p>
        <label for="byour_name">Your name</label><input type="text" name="byour_name" value="" id="byour_name">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="byour_email_address">Your email address</label><input type="text" name="byour_email_address" value="" id="byour_email_address">
    </p>
    <p>
        What's on your mind?<br>
        <textarea name="Message" rows="10" cols="25"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Send it!" onClick="sendMail()">
    </p>
</form>

function sendMail() {
    $.ajax( {
        url: "/email",
       type: "POST",
       data: $("#myContactForm").serialize(),
    success: function( response) {
                alert(response);
             },
      error: function() {
                alert('failure');
    }
    });
}
```

Every time I make request error function is executing.I am writing app on google app engine. I am keep getting this error:

```
self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

My post request handler is:

```
def post(self):

    Content = self.request.get("Message")
    byName = self.request.get("byour_name")
    byEmailAddress = self.request.get("byour_email_address")

    gmailUser = 'id@gmail.com'
    gmailPassword = 'password'
    dataSend = byName

    mail.send_mail(sender  = gmailUser,
                   to      = gmailUser,
                   subject ="Email Sent By : "+ byName + "@" + byEmailAddress,
                   body    = Content)
    self.response.out.write(byEmailAddress)
```

And after I click submit button URl changes to:

```
http://localhost:8080/?byour_name=username&byour_email_address=userEmail@gmail.com%40gmail.com&Message=mlm%0D%0A#contact
```

as I am making a get request can someone help me..But how post request changes to get request.

Comment: If i wanted to use form post i would have i want to use ajax post to stop redirection and as well perform form validation on the client side..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove form tag and the get the desired values by id and then use ajax method. Because may be ajax post and form request method are conflicting. I think form has default get method as you said earlier may be that's the reason whenever you click on submit first ajax post make request soon after form get method and may be that's the reason the error is thrown by your server.

Comment: Thanks man you are right i tried that myself and it worked as soon as i removed form tag everything worked like charm

Answer (score 1):

You're not preventing the default submit. Either return false from your sendMail function, or take the event as a parameter and call `preventDefault()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what your trying to do , to fix this you can do the following:

remove onclick="sendMail()"

and change your JavaScript function to something like:

```
$('#myContactForm').submit(function () {
  $.ajax( {
    url: "/email",
    type: "POST",
    data: $("#myContactForm").serialize(),success: 
      function( response) {   
        alert(response);         
      },                  
      error: function(){                                              
        alert('failure');                                    
      }
    });
});
```